# How can select first child/last child of class in a mixed container?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can I select the first and last children of a class in a div that has children of with various classes?

For example:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>

    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select first-child and last-child of `.black`. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to select the first child of the first .black, and the last child of the last .black or the first and last child of EACH .black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`nth-child`](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/nthchild.html) or [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) in combination with the class selector.

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Z8m/2/)

```
.main .black:nth-child(2n) {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Or if you want them to be separate

[**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Z8m/3/)

```
.main .black:nth-child(5n - 6) {
    color: yellow;
}
.main .black:nth-child(5n - 4) {
    color:purple;
}
```

The function calculates using `n = element of type`, so `:nth-child(n)` would select every element, `:nth-child(2n)` selects all odd elements, `:nth-child(2n-1)` selects all even elements, and so on. You simply have to come up with a function that gets you the elements you want

Another option may be to add another class to the first and/or last element of class

You can select the first child with a dynamic number of elements with the class by combining two selectors like Jonathan said (I prefer `div:not(.black) + div.black` personally). However, the only way to select the last element with a class with a dynamic number of elements given there is no previous sibling selector is to use Javascript or a library like jQuery as follows:

Javascript

```
var blackElems = document.getElementsByClassName('black');
blackElems[blackElems.length - 1].style.color = 'purple';
```

jQuery

```
$('.main .black:last').css({ 'color' : 'purple' });
```

Comment: This is not extensible if the number of elements changes

Comment: @ohmusama "You simply have to come up with a function that gets you the elements you want"

Comment: Your suggestion is to have a dynamic css file that can't be cached then? (if the page has a dynamic number of elements on it)

Comment: @ohmusama The OP didn't mention the need for elements to be of dynamic length, but I added a javascript solution if that is the case given it's impossible to do in pure CSS currently

Comment: It would be better to use `:nth-child` instead of `:nth-of-type` here given that all the elements are of the same type `div` anyway, to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately not.

However, it is possible to select the first child of a certain class, by combining two selectors (**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/CBc38/)**):

```
div.black:first-child,
div:not(.black) + div.black
```

The first selector selects a black div that's apparently the first child of it's parent. The second selector selects a black div that's preceded by a non-black div. Using these two rules, you can select the first black div.

For more information, see: [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child), [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot), and the [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).