# CSS Selector for last-of-type/last-child but different parents?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Would like to access item 6 only through css

```html
<div class="div-class">
  <li class="li-class">Item 1</li>
  <li class="li-class">Item 2</li>
  <li class="li-class">Item 3</li>
</div>
<div class="div-class">
  <li class="li-class">Item 4</li>
  <li class="li-class">Item 5</li>
  <li class="li-class">Item 6</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select :last-child with especific class name (with only css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598620/select-last-child-with-especific-class-name-with-only-css)

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

I think that it is duplicate. [Select :last-child with especific class name (with only css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598620/select-last-child-with-especific-class-name-with-only-css)

So you need which div you want to point. In this case, this is second div so we specified:

```
div:nth-child(2)
```

And then we just select last li as below:

```
li:last-child
```

So finaly we got:

```
div:nth-child(2) li:last-child{
  background-color: red;
}
```

### EDIT

With jQuery:

```
$('li').last().css('background', 'red');
```

Just to let you know, your html structure is incorrect as you should set li right after `ul` or `ol`

```js
$('li').last().css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</div>
<div>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the divs are on different pages? This keeps editing Item 3 in addition to Item 6...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: @dippas ok then I will stop that, thank you

Comment: @mtd so you wish to focus the very last li, no matter the number of ul or ol ?

Comment: @MaxiGui What if the divs are on different pages? This keeps editing Item 3 in addition to Item 6...

Comment: yes! The divs are on separate pages... I just want the very last kind of li with class name "li-class"

Comment: ok I will search for that

Comment: @mtd Here you go with jQuery, If I find solution with css only I will come back to you